# Bootstrap 4 Data table - Get Pagination event with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, pagination

I have the following table on my `cshtml`:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr align="left">
            <th>
                //header
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                //Body
            </td>

        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It creates the pagination itself. inspecting the code I can see that the pagination element is the following:

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate"><ul class="pagination">
```

The problem here is that I need to capture the click on the pagination to send the page number to the server, I've already tried to add an `onClick` to that id selfgenerated on the view but it's not working.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add id to href of anchor tag,here is a demo:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pageNum=1">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pageNum=2">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pageNum=3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```